How to change some columns in CSV file
I have a file that looks like this:
CNPJ,73811717000167,ABC,04886747000140,ATIVO,2020-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00,null,2020-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00,2020-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00
CNPJ,71179825000180,ABC,01234567000199,ATIVO,2021-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00,ATIVO,2021-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00,2021-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00

I want to change every datetime column ($6, $8, $9) to look like this: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
Ex: 2020-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00 becomes 2020-04-22 16:21:47
AND where I get null (for any column) it should be empty.
For the null, it is as simple as:
sed -i 's/null//g' teste_kiki.csv

But how do I do the date change? Do you guys have any idea?
I saw some options, but all only replacing the entire column with a value. Not changing a part of the column (the T and the part after .)
What I saw was something like this (changing the column 6 to the value 1.
awk -F \, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}
    {$6=1; print}' teste_kiki.csv

The code above changes the entire column 6 to 1. And that is not what I want.
awk -F \, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}
    {$6={sed 's/T/ '};
      print}' teste_kiki.csv

I tried the above, but it returns error:

awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
awk: line 2: missing } near end of file


please update the question with a sample row that contains some null values; can the null show up in any column or just the 3x date columns?

can any of the fields contain a comma as part of the data? can any of the fields have null as a substring (eg, this is nullable) and if so are we to replace the substring or should we only replace null if it is the entire content of the field?
if the answer is 'yes' to either question then please update the question with a sample of such a row

Regarding awk -F \, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{$6={sed 's/T/ '}; print}' teste_kiki.csv- trying to call sed from awk is like trying to call Python from Ruby. sed and awk are 2 completely different tools and both are different from bash (yet another tool). Hence the syntax error.

s/null//g or similar that matches across the whole line without anchors is dangerous as it would convert disannulled to disaned. Match using anchors or full fields instead of whole lines.

One option could be using sed and  capture the part of the date time format that you want to keep with a regex, and match what you don't want to keep.
In the replacement use the 2 capture groups separated by a space, where group 1 has the date, and group 2 has the time.
sed -E 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})[0-9.:-]+/\1 \2/g' file

Output
CNPJ,71179825000180,ABC,01234567000199,ATIVO,2021-04-22 16:21:47,ATIVO,2021-04-22 16:21:47,2021-04-22 16:21:47


If you can make use of gnu awk you can use the regex with 2 capture groups and set the column value to the concatenation of those 2 group values divided by a space if there is a match.
In the begin block, set the field separators to a comma, and then for example create a loop to check for a match and set the column value for column 6, 8 and 9.
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
    regex = "([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})"
    split("6 8 9", columns, " ")
}
{
    for (j in columns) {
        i = columns[j]
        if (match($i, regex, ary)) {
            $i = ary[1] " " ary[2]
        }
    }
} 1' file

Output
CNPJ,71179825000180,ABC,01234567000199,ATIVO,2021-04-22 16:21:47,ATIVO,2021-04-22 16:21:47,2021-04-22 16:21:47


Assumptions:

we do not have to worry about commas showing up as part of the data fields
null (all lowercase) should be replaced with a single space only when it represents the entire content of the field (eg, we do not change this is nullable to this is  able)
any field can contain null
OP knows the date/time field numbers up front (otherwise we could expand the proposed awk code to dynamically look for date/time formatted fields)

General design:

provide awk with a list of the fields that are in date/time format
save these field numbers as indices in an array (dtcols[])
for each field in an input line:
a) if the field == null then replace with a space
b) if the field number is an index in the dtcols[] array then split the field on dual delimiters T and . and redefine the field as the first two entries from the split/array

Sample data:
$ cat teste_kiki.csv
CNPJ,71179825000180,ABC,01234567000199,ATIVO,2021-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00,ATIVO,2021-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00,2021-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00
XYZ1,999_null_34343,null,01234567000199,ATIVO,null,ATIVO,2021-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00,2021-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00
                    ^^^^-change               ^^^^-change
         ^^^^-do not change

NOTE: ^^^^ lines are added here as highlights and do not exist in actual file
One awk idea:
awk -v fldlist='6,8,9' '                    # provide list of date/time formatted fields
BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","                      # input/output field separator = ","
        split(fldlist,a)                    # split dtlist into array a[]; in this example a[1]=6, a[2]=8, a[3]=9
        for (i in a) dtcols[a[i]]           # build dtcols[] array; in this example dtcols[6]= , dtcols[8]= , dtcols[9]=
      }
      { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {             # loop through each field of the current input line
                 if ($i == "null")          # replace "null" ...
                    $i=" "                  # with space
            else if (i in dtcols) {         # if field number is an index in dtcols[] array ...
                    split($i,a,"[T.]")      # split field on delimiters "T" and "." and put results in array a[]
                    $i = a[1] " " a[2]      # redefine the field
            }
        }
      }
1                                           # print current/newly-modified line
' teste_kiki.csv

This generates:
CNPJ,71179825000180,ABC,01234567000199,ATIVO,2021-04-22 16:21:47,ATIVO,2021-04-22 16:21:47,2021-04-22 16:21:47
XYZ1,999_null_34343, ,01234567000199,ATIVO, ,ATIVO,2021-04-22 16:21:47,2021-04-22 16:21:47


If your CSV can have quoted fields, commas or newlines in fields, etc., you need a real CSV parser or a recent version of GNU awk:
$ cat foo.awk
function p(f, i) {
  f = i in idx ? gensub(r, "\\1 \\2", "1", f) : f
  f = f ~ /[,"\n]/ ? "\"" gensub(/"/, "\"\"", "g", f) "\"" : f
  return f == "null" ? "" : f
}

BEGIN {OFS = ","; idx[6]; idx[8]; idx[9]; r = @/(.*)T(.*)\..*/}
{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) $i = p($i, i); print }

And then, to process foo.csv:
$ awk -k -f foo.awk foo.csv

The -k option parses any correctly formatted comma-separated CSV. The p function applies reformatting of dates on the selected fields. It also post-processes the fields to produce again correctly CSV formatted fields: it doubles the double-quotes, and quotes the fields if they contain double-quotes, commas or newlines. It also implements the replacement of null fields with an empty string.
Demo with quoted fields, commas and newlines in fields, and a null:
$ cat foo.csv
CNPJ,71179825000180,ABC,"0123456,700
0199","AT""IV,O",null,"ATI
VO","2021-0
4-22T16:21:47.758-03:00",2021-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00

$ awk -k -f foo.awk foo.csv
CNPJ,71179825000180,ABC,"0123456,700
0199","AT""IV,O",,"ATI
VO","2021-0
4-22 16:21:47",2021-04-22 16:21:47



Ex: 2020-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00 becomes 2020-04-22 16:21:47

I suggest using substr string function twice to extract desired part and then concat using space character. You might define own Function as you want to apply it to more than 1 column. Let file.csv content be
2020-04-22T16:21:47.758-03:00,A,2020-04-22T16:25:47.758-03:00
2020-04-22T16:25:47.758-03:00,B,2020-04-22T16:27:47.758-03:00
2020-04-22T16:27:47.758-03:00,C,2020-04-22T16:29:47.758-03:00

then
awk 'function reformat(datetime){return substr(datetime,1,10) " " substr(datetime,12,8)}BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$1=reformat($1);$3=reformat($3);print}' file.csv

gives output
2020-04-22 16:21:47,A,2020-04-22 16:25:47
2020-04-22 16:25:47,B,2020-04-22 16:27:47
2020-04-22 16:27:47,C,2020-04-22 16:29:47

Explanation: I use said substr function to get substring of length 10 starting at 1st character and substring of length 8 starting at 12th character and concat them using single space character. I use defined function to get new values which I assign to 1st and 3rd columns.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Using sed
$ sed -E ':a;s/ (,)/\1/;s/([0-9-]+)T([0-9:]*)[^,]*|,*null/\1 \2/;ta' input_file
CNPJ,73811717000167,ABC,04886747000140,ATIVO,2020-04-22 16:21:47,2020-04-22 16:21:47,2020-04-22 16:21:47
CNPJ,71179825000180,ABC,01234567000199,ATIVO,2021-04-22 16:21:47,ATIVO,2021-04-22 16:21:47,2021-04-22 16:21:47


Using any awk:
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( $i == "null" ) {
                $i = ""
            }
            else if ( i ~ /^[689]$/ ) {
                sub(/T/, " ", $i)
                sub(/\..*/, "", $i)
            }
        }
        print
    }
' file
CNPJ,73811717000167,ABC,04886747000140,ATIVO,2020-04-22 16:21:47,,2020-04-22 16:21:47,2020-04-22 16:21:47
CNPJ,71179825000180,ABC,01234567000199,ATIVO,2021-04-22 16:21:47,ATIVO,2021-04-22 16:21:47,2021-04-22 16:21:47

Change i ~ /^[689]$/ to $i ~ /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}T[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){2}\.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/ or similar using a POSIX awk if you want to match any field that looks like a timestamp rather than change a specific set of field numbers that you expect to contain timestamps.

This command replaces 'T' with ' ' in the columns 6, 8, 9:
awk -F\, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{gsub("T"," ",$6); gsub("T"," ",$8); gsub("T"," ",$9); print}' teste_kiki.csv

It doesn't matter what the date-time format is.
